# Measuring average response time from downstream Restful API's

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights, dotnet-httpclient

We have a Web API written in ASP.Net core 3.1 which calls 5 different downstream RESTful API's.
P50 of our API is greater than 5 seconds which is huge. This Web API is hosted as an Azure App Service and logs are shipped on Azure App Insights.

We would like to know what are the best tools or framework's or any another way in Azure monitoring or kql query which can be used to measure average response time or throughput of those 5 different downstream RESTful API's. We would like to identify which downstream API is downgrading the overall Web API performance

We have tried Azure App insights. It gives time taken by individual request but haven't found anything which can help measure average response time of downstream API's

Answer (score 0):

Downstream rest api calls are recorded as dependencies of type HTTP in application insights. You can correlate them with the api request using the operation_Id.

Try a query like this:

```
requests
| project timestamp, url, requestDuration = duration, operation_Id
| join kind=inner (dependencies | where ['type'] == "HTTP" | project dependencytimestamp = timestamp, operation_Id, dependencyDuration = duration, dependencyUrl = data) on operation_Id
| project  timestamp, operation_Id, url, requestDuration, dependencytimestamp, dependencyUrl, dependencyDuration
```